# What are the names for these two pieces of a car chassis and a piece for above the wheels?

Tags: part-identification, vehicle

I have the following pieces but cannot find their names nor precise usage on BrickLink or elsewhere

The black one has a wheel well on each side - sorry for the poor image quality.

Both the red and black will touch the wheels I have unless I stick a thin piece between them

Please show me an example on how I use them and what the blue piece is for.

[[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- [image]: [3787](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/3787) — Car Mudguard 2 x 4 without Studs
- [image]: [4211](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/4211) — Car Base 4 x 5
- [image]: [4732](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/4732) — Bracket 8 x 2 x 1 1/3

In the link for each piece, you'll find actual sets containing them, from which you can find set instructions. In particular, the two mudguard ones need to be one plate apart from regular wheel sets.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks - did you know this or can you reveal your deduction?

Comment: http://www.peeron.com/scans/6632-1/2

Comment: I don't know all of this by heart, no. For the red and black one, I searched for "[mudguard](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/psearch?query=mudguard&limit=parts)", and for the blue one for "bracket" (I knew at least that). Sinc the black one did not have "mudguard" in it, I had to use another approach: look for a set which had it, knowing [ambulances](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=ambulance) would be a good start, and then look at the [inventory](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/6680-1).

Comment: That is so strange - when I search for mudguard, I get single mudguards... Anyway, thanks